# How to modify crontab for other users using sudo in script

Tags: linux, bash, automation

I would like to automate adding lines to crontab for technical users. I don't know the passwords so the only way I can do this is using sudo -u USER . I wrote the following loop but it updates crontab for the user that I'm logged in, not for the users I provide in sudo command. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
for i in $(cat users.txt); do
    sudo -u USERNAME_$i echo "$(echo '* 1 * * * some_command_2' ; crontab -l 2>&1)" | crontab 
done
```

EDIT: I made a mistake in the above code, now it's correct but it's not working

Comment: Read the Bash manual and understand how script syntax actually works. Don't guess.

Comment: Could you point me to something specific? It's not one page and I have no idea where should I look for the answer. I don't need to put this into the script, it can be simple loop to run in OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through the code.

```
for i in $(cat users.txt); do
    sudo -u USERNAME_$i echo "$(echo '* 1 * * * some_command_2' ; crontab -l 2>&1)" | crontab 
done
```

First the `sudo`. You will execute the first `echo` as root. Your `bash` will first determine what arguments need to be given to `sudo`. The last argument is `"$(echo '* 1 * * * some_command_2' ; crontab -l 2>&1)"` The shell under your own userID will expand this before it is given as argument to `sudo`. You can easily see this if you add `id`.

```
sudo echo "$(echo '* 1 * * * some_command_2' ; crontab -l 2>&1 ; id)"
```

which will show that `id` is executed under your own ID.

The next possible problem is your list of userid's in `users.txt`. All of the users that the `sudo` gets are prefixed with `USERNAME_`. It is unlikely (though possible) that that is what you want.

Third problem is the second `crontab`. This is also executed under your own userID, thereby adding all the stuf to your own crontab. That is also not what you want.

About `sudo`: sudo *does not* run the rest of the line as the new user, only the command that is given directly after it.

So, how to solve this?

Get rid of the useless `echo`, `sudo` what must be sudoed  and use `crontab -u`.

So that would be something like:

```
for name in $(cat users.txt); do
    (echo '* 1 * * * some_command_2' ; sudo crontab -lu "$name") | sudo crontab -u "$name" 
done
```

This will probably work.

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever gotten! Thank you very much! I appreciate this